# Determine the set of all $x∈ℝ$ satifying $x^2 + |x-1| ≤ 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Determine the set of all $x∈ℝ$ satifying $x^2 + |x-1| ≤ 1$

My working out so far:

$|x-1|$ =

$x-1$ when $x≥1$

$1-x$ when $x<1$

Then we compute $x^2 + |x-1|$ as follows:

$x^2 + |x-1|$ =

$x^2 +x -1$ when $x≥1$

$x^2 - x + 1$ when $x<1$

So we have the following 2 cases:

i) When $x≥1$, we get $x^2 + |x-1| = x^2 +x -1$ and substituting this into the inequality $x^2 + |x-1| ≤ 1$ gives $x^2 + x-2≤0$. Hence we get $x≤1$ when $x≥1$.

ii) When $x<1$ we get $x^2 + |x-1| = x^2 -x +1$ and substituting into the inequality we get $x^2 - x +1 ≤ 1$ therfore $x^2-x ≤ 0$, factorising we get $x(x-1)≤0$, so we have $x≤0$ and $x≤1$

Not sure if this is correct, I feel there's a contradiction in the second part. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you mean, $x-1$ when $x\geq 0$ and $1-x$ when $x<0$?

Comment: No I don't think so, because the right-hand side of the equation is 1, unless my whole method is wrong..? @ProtectedSource

Comment: Maybe I didn't quite understand your method. What I was thinking was solving for two cases for the absolute value, and then setting the RHS to $0$ and solving for $x$ in both cases.

Comment: You got $x(x-1) \leq 0$ in second part. Since $x-1$ is negative you must have $x$ positive (product of two negative numbers is positive, tight?). This is where you made a mistake in your argument. @Neels

Comment: There are several ways to solve your problem. One of them is as follow:
Let $\epsilon$ a real positive. You have for $x+\epsilon$ and for $-\epsilon$ that $LHS$ and $LHS$ are greater than $1$. Besides if $x=0$ and $x=1$ then $LHS=1$ What form have you to say that $x\in[0,1]$? (you can for example take in particular $x=\dfrac12$, what more?)

Answer (score 2):

You have almost got it right but the final conclusion is as follows: for $x \geq 1$ we get $x=1$ and for $x <1$ the answer is $0\leq x <1$. Hence the final answer is $0\leq x \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You may rewrite the inequality first:

$$x^2 + |x-1| \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow |1-x| \leq 1-x^2 = (1-x)(1+x)$$

- $\color{blue}{x= 1}$ is an obvious solution.

For $x \neq 1$ you get

$$|1-x| \leq (1-x)(1+x) \stackrel{\color{blue}{x \neq 1}}{\Longleftrightarrow} \begin{cases} 1 \leq -(1+x) & \mbox{ for } x > 1 \\ 1\leq 1+x & \mbox{ for } x <1 \end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} x \leq -2 & \mbox{ for } x > 1  \color{red}{\mbox{ no solution}} \\ \color{blue}{0 \leq x} & \mbox{ for } \color{blue}{x <1} \end{cases}$$

All together
$$\color{blue}{\boxed{0 \leq x \leq 1}}$$